# html5 mobile app in landscape mode and portrait mode

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have design an html5 android app using bootstrap 3.3 and i have display 12 col in portrait mode

col-xs-12

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-6">
  <div class="panel panel-card">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="bottom text-white p">
        Title
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p">
      <h3>Paracosm</h3>
      <p>
        The titles of Washed Out's breakthrough song and the first single from Paracosm share the
        two most important words in Ernest Greene's musical language: feel it. It's a simple request, as well...
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to display 6 col in landscape mode how to do this..

col-xs-6